# save WAV file encoded base64

Tags: javascript, base64, wav

I want decode again and save file a WAV file that encoded base64 with javascript pure solution

I can play it with this code:
var snd = Sound("data:audio/wav;base64," + myaudio);

but i need to save it not playing

Comment: try with snd.noteOff(0); i think this will help

Comment: @HackerGK .noteOff(0); save base64 in wav format?

Comment: I'm not sure browser security will permit javascript to write directly to the file system - you would probably have to send it to a sever so it can be opened as a download.